# Periodically run useEffect for Dashboard API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

I'm looking to periodically call an API and return the response to be displayed on the page. This API is to get the message count on an Azure queue, and then display it on my dashboard.

I have tried many options but I cant seem t get it to work. I'm using setIntervalAsync to periodically call the API but currently it is only returning undefined once. Below is the code used to make the call:

```
export function Something() {
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => 
  getProperties().then(data => {return data.Count}), 1000);
}, [])}
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:
Using the updated code below, I now receive the call periodically but cannot seem to get into to display.

```
export const Queue = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const h = setIntervalAsync(() => {
      getProperties().then(data => {
        setCount(data.Count)
        console.log("First: " + count)
      })
    }, 1000)
    console.log("Second: " + count)

    return () => { clearInterval(h) }
  }, [count])
  console.log("Third: " + count)

  return <div>{count}</div>
}
```

Here is where I call the function:

```
export let Content = () => {
  let count = Queue()
  console.log(count)
  return (
    <div className="grid">
      <h1 className="title">Queues</h1>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="column">
          <h3>count</h3>
          <h2 id='Count'>{count}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a screenshot from what is returned form the console logs:

[image]

As you can see it is called periodically within the useEffect but doesn't reach outside periodically, only once

Comment: Don’t return. Instead update state

Comment: The `Queue` is a component, just like `h2`. So to include it, put it like `<Queue />`, not `const a = Queue`.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, but will this update it when the count changes??

Comment: yes, that's how React is designed. as long as `useState` inside the `Queue` is called, it'll update the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you call the interval right, however to ask *React* to do things, you need to notify it. Assuming you put this stuff in `App`.

```
  const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(-1)

    useEffect(() => {
      const h = setInterval(() => {
        getProperties().then(data => {
          // trigger an update to screen
          setCount(data.Count)
        })
      }, 1000)

      // clean interval upon dismount
      return () => { clearInterval(h) }

    }, [])

    // this is for you to see the work
    return <div>{count}</div>
  }
```

I added two things on top of your work:

- `setCount` is used to wire your logic with an update
- `useEffect` returns a destroy function to clean stuff